# Calling Permalinks With PHP

Tags: posts, excerpt

I'm developing a theme which supports WordPress' post formats.  As a result I am using a big if statement, which can be found below.

- I would like to link my post titles to the posts while maintaining my theme as XHTML valid.
- I would like to call images (with classes) in the if statement while maintaining my theme as XHTML valid.
- I would appreciate if somebody could add the appropriate code to the following code to do so

_

```
if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) {
                echo the_title();
                echo the_excerpt();
}
```

**EDIT: Basically, the most important thing I'm looking for is that it calls the post name as a link which links to the actual post.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "call images", but this will display the title as a link.

```
if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) {
   ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><?php 
   the_excerpt();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't link to the post, just to the homepage.  Also, it outputs the permalink onto the page when I'm just trying to get it to link to the_title()

Comment: Corrected the code. The echo was slightly broken. Also, your code didn't need echos in the first place, which I missed.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add in the `<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>` to link the post and also add the title as the visible part of the link. Also you can replace `<?php the_title();?>` for a thumbnail (with the correct funct.) or an image, a video, a button, etc. and another kind of php stament as well `<?php your_function(your args);?>`.

As far as your other question goes, I think that you'll need to add a category for videos and make an special CSS for that. I'll leave two posts, they are in spanish but they are really useful and they work very well: first how to add a different structure [How to: different structure per category](http://www.dinvaders.com/wordpress-como-hacer-un-template-diferente-para-cada-categoria/) and then how to style it [How to: style each category differently](http://www.dinvaders.com/wordpress-diferentes-estilos-css-por-categoria/)

Hope you find this response helpful ^^

Comment: That's getting me closer, but still not quite there.  Basically, I want to link echo the_title(); to the post.

Answer (score 0):

So:

```
<?php if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
    <?php the_excerpt();?>
<?php } else {;?> If you plan on adding something else. otherwise just delete this line and close with the next one only

<?php } ;?>
```

And that's it, hope you find this helpful!!